# Removing foreign key using Matthuhiggins foreign_key?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have no problem with adding the foreign key constraint with this gem:

http://github.com/matthuhiggins/foreigner

However, I cannot remove the foreign key.

```
class ForeignKeys < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up
    add_foreign_key(:threads, :users)
  end

  def self.down
    remove_foreign_key(:threads, :column => :user_id)
  end
end
```

Could someone help me out here.

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This the last thing I can think of.

```
def self.down
    execute 'ALTER TABLE threads DROP FOREIGN KEY user_id'
end
```

---

### OLD ONE

These should work :)

```
remove_foreign_key :threads, { :column => :user_id }
```

or

```
remove_foreign_key('threads', 'user_id')
```

or

```
remove_foreign_key(:threads, :user_id)
```

Petr

Comment: It does not work on PostgreSQL. The correct syntax is `ALTER TABLE threads DROP CONSTRAINT user_id` (or even `user_id_fk`)

Comment: This worked for me on postgresql: 
`remove_foreign_key('threads', 'user')`

Comment: In case anyone has upgraded to Rails 4.2, there is now baked in foreign key support per [release notes](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/4_2_release_notes.html#foreign-key-support)

Answer (score 4):

The best solution is

`remove_foreign_key :threads, :users`

However, the following should have also worked:

`remove_foreign_key :threads, :column => :user_id`

If it didn't, file a bug on my library.